# How to solve this Terminal issue

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I want to create an Angular project but as soon as I do "ng new nameproject", my terminal does that. I don't know what to look for to solve my problem.

[My terminal problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PViCl.png)

Comment: Your image is empty. Provide some details on what is the error you are facing.

Comment: Really ? Ok. 
It's written at the bottom of the terminal : 
" --**-Mg: nameproject" followed by "(fundamental) ----All ----------------------------"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You entered [`mg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mg_(editor)) instead of [`ng`](https://cli.angular.io/).

Comment: No, no. I wrote ng. But yes, it's written mg below.

Comment: Do you have an alias defined that points `ng` to `mg` by any chance? Any output when you type `alias ng`?

Comment: No, nothing. I typed "alias ng" and nothing occured.

Comment: What do you get from `which ng`?

Comment: This : " /usr/bin/ng "

Comment: In the end, you're right. It was an alias. I did "sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin
" to solve my issue. Thanks for help !